# Playing Youtube video in webview without all the information arround it

Tags: react-native, webview, expo

I would like playing a Youtube Video in Webview without all the information arround it (video suggested, etc)
The movie is correctly displayed in my app (without the fullscreen function .. but that's another point) 
i just want to hide the information

Comment: You can't hide those info (https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#release_notes_08_23_2018). The only things you can hide are controls (https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#controls) and logo (https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#modestbranding).

Comment: that means users can do anything they want  as soon as they are on Youtube

Comment: you may use `onShouldStartLoadWithRequest` to restrict their browsing